# Roll up count in hierarchical table(self referential table)

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, self-referencing-table

I Have a table in the below format.This is a self referential table where each record points to its parent record.

```
NODE_ID  PARENT_ID  COUNT
1        0          NULL
2        1          NULL
3        2          10
4        2          12
5        0          NULL
6        5          NULL
7        6          NULL
8        7          12
```

I want the output to be in below format.The count of parent should be the sum of count of leaf childs.
**Note: Only the leaf childs will contain the count. I want to roll it up till parents.**

```
NODE_ID  PARENT_ID  COUNT
1        0          22
2        1          22
3        2          10
4        2          12
5        0          12
6        5          12
7        6          12
8        7          12
```

Please help.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I think you misread the output.  Node `2` has two children with a total count of `22`.  In turn, node `1` only has `2` as a child, who has a count of `22`.  He probably needs a recursive query of some sort.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen You are right.I want the  sum of counts of direct childs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I couldn't think of anything simpler:

```sql
;WITH GetLevelsCTE AS (
   SELECT NODE_ID, PARENT_ID, COUNT, level = 1, ROOT = NODE_ID
   FROM mytable
   WHERE PARENT_ID = 0

   UNION ALL

   SELECT t1.NODE_ID, t1.PARENT_ID, t1.COUNT, level = t2.level + 1, t2.ROOT
   FROM mytable AS t1
   JOIN GetLevelsCTE AS t2 ON t2.NODE_ID = t1.PARENT_ID
), MaxLevelCTE AS (
   -- Get MAX level per root NODE_ID
   SELECT MAX(level) AS max_level, ROOT
   FROM GetLevelsCTE
   GROUP BY ROOT
), GetCountCTE AS (
   -- Anchor query: start from the bottom 
   SELECT t1.NODE_ID, t1.PARENT_ID, t1.COUNT, t1.level
   FROM GetLevelsCTE AS t1
   JOIN MaxLevelCTE AS t2 ON t1.ROOT = t2.ROOT 
   WHERE t1.level = t2.max_level

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive query: get counts of next level
   SELECT t1.NODE_ID, t1.PARENT_ID, t2.COUNT, t1.level
   FROM GetLevelsCTE AS t1
   JOIN GetCountCTE AS t2 ON t1.level = t2.level - 1 AND t1.NODE_ID = t2.PARENT_ID
)
SELECT NODE_ID, PARENT_ID, SUM(COUNT) AS COUNT
FROM GetCountCTE
GROUP BY NODE_ID, PARENT_ID
ORDER BY NODE_ID
```

Short explanation:

- `GetLevelsCTE` is used to assign a `level` number to every node of the tree.
- `MaxLevelCTE` uses the previous `CTE` in order the obtain the maximum level of the tree.
- `GetCountCTE` uses both previous `CTEs` in order to traverse the tree from the bottom to the parent node. This way, the `COUNT` is propagated to the parent node.

Comment: :Thanks for replaying. Your query is only valid if there is only one level of hierarchy. If in the same table i have two top level parents (node with no parents or parent id 0), then it will not work out .I hope you got my concern.

Comment: I have updated the question table. Parent id 0 means the root of the tree hierarchy .

Comment: My mistake, issue is replicated if the dept of trees in the table is different.edited the question.

Comment: Corrected in question.